# Robolectric with Gradle: package org.robolectric does not exist

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, robolectric

I am trying to run robolectric tests with gradle android build system. I have followed the  [**instructions given here**](https://github.com/novoda/robolectric-plugin#gradle-plugin-for-running-local-robolectric-test) to try to make it work but while running tests using **gradle robolectric** I am badly stuck at the following error -

```
/Users/Sreekanth/Documents/artoo/Code/Android/HelloWorld/src/test/java/com/example/helloworld/MyTest.java:8: package org.robolectric does not exist
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
```

My Project has the following structure -

```
 .
 ├── AndroidManifest.xml
 ├── assets
 ├── bin
 ├── build.gradle
 ├── gen
 ├── libs
 ├── res
 └── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── com
    │           └── example
    │               └── helloworld
    │                   ├── MainActivity.java
    └── test
        └── java
            └── com
                └── example
                    └── helloworld
                        └── MyTest.java
```

Here is my **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
        classpath 'com.novoda.gradle:robolectric-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'
apply plugin: 'maven'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    robolectricCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.0'
    robolectricCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

repositories {

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
         url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
     defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}
```

My MyTest.java file:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyTest {


    @Test
    public void shouldHaveHappySmiles() throws Exception {
        String appName = new MainActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        assertThat(appName, equalTo("My Application"));
    }
}
```

I can successfully run robolectric tests if I am using the new gradle project structure but not if I am using old eclipse project structure like the one mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the new structure, period. The robolectric plugin has that path hardcoded. You could probably set the sourceSet from your build script but it would be hacky and not "official".

Comment: Gradle is successfully able to identify my test class location but its not using robolectric configuration(which has org.robolectric as dependency) to compile it. I tried adding `sourceSets.robolectric.java.srcDir file('src/test/java')` to my build.gradle, but no luck.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you using the "new" structure (src/main/java, src/test/java) or the Eclipse one? Try moving the `apply: 'robolectric'` line after the `android{}` block.

Comment: Still the same issue. My project structure is mentioned in my question above. Its src/main/java,src/test/java but all other folders like "res" are present at the root level instead of inside "src/main".

Comment: Two things - `java.srcDirs = ['src']` means that ALL java source for `main` will start from `src/`, which goes against what you're saying. Second, the actual error seems to deal with dependencies - try removing your `build` and `.gradle` folders and try again.

Comment: Writing `java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']` resolved my previous error. But now I got stuck at this error - `MyTest.java:16: cannot access android.app.Activity   class file for android.app.Activity not found`. Any idea what is going wrong ?